# signup with react native Expo and firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo

I'm trying to add user in firebase , it just takes the email and password but not for the other variables, and now I have this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined    (reading 'username')
> at children (SignUUp.js:105:1) 
> at Formik (Formik.tsx:1026:1)
> at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
> at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)

here is my code :

```js
    import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button, Alert, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
    import {firebase_Auth} from '../../global/Data'
    import { Formik } from 'formik';
    import { Firestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
    import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';

    export function SignUUp({navigation}) {
      
        const auth =firebase_Auth;

        const  varstate = {
                    username: '',
                    email: '',
                    password: '',
                    isLoading: false
                };

           
        async function signUp(values){

            const {email,password} = values
          
            try{
              await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth,email,password).then(
                (res)=>{
                  Firestore.database().ref('users/',res.user.uid).set({
                    "username": values.username
                  })
                }
              )
              console.log("USER ACCOUNT CREATED")
            }
            
            catch(error){

              if(error.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use'){
                Alert.alert(
                  'That email address is already inuse'
                )
              }

              if(error.code === 'auth/invalid-email'){
                Alert.alert(
                  'That email address is invalid'
                )
              }

              else{
                Alert.alert(error.code)
              }
            }
          }
          
            {
                if (varstate.isLoading) {
                    return (
                        <View style={styles.preloader}>
                            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#9E9E9E" />
                        </View>
                    );
                }

                return (
                    <Formik  varstate ={varstate} onSubmit = {(values)=>{signUp(values)}}>
                        {(props)=>(
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        <TextInput
                            style={styles.inputStyle}
                            placeholder="username"
                            onChangeText={props.handleChange('username')}
                            value={props.values.username}
                            />
                        <TextInput
                            style={styles.inputStyle}
                            placeholder="Email"
                            onChangeText = {props.handleChange('email')}
                            value = {props.values.email}/>
                        <TextInput
                            style={styles.inputStyle}
                            placeholder="Password"
                            value={props.values.password}
                            onChangeText={props.handleChange('password')}
                            maxLength={15}
                            secureTextEntry={true} />
                        <Button
                            color="#3740FE"
                            title="Signup"
                            onPress = {props.handleSubmit}
                           />
                        <Text
                            style={styles.loginText}
                            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignInScreen')}>
                            Already Registered? Click here to login
                        </Text>
                    </View>
           ) }
                    </Formik>
                );
            }
        
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "center",
        padding: 35,
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
      },
      inputStyle: {
        width: '100%',
        marginBottom: 15,
        paddingBottom: 15,
        alignSelf: "center",
        borderColor: "#ccc",
        borderBottomWidth: 1
      },
      loginText: {
        color: '#3740FE',
        marginTop: 25,
        textAlign: 'center'
      },
      preloader: {
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        position: 'absolute',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
      }
    });
```

In firebase I create a collection users with  element username
the ligne of the code  is :
    `value={props.values.username}`

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.